# SQL script to change all table references in all stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a new database with copies of existing tables but changed the names of these tables, is there a SQL script that I can run (maybe using SysObjects) to change all references to these tables in all stored procedures?

Comment: I assume SQL Server from mention of `sysobjects`? If so which version?

Comment: Generate scripts for your stored procedures and then do a find and replace on all the table names that you have changed ...

Comment: **don't run UPDATE commands on the system tables!!!!** script out the necessary procedures, make the changes (search/replace or manually), and then run the scripts!!!

Comment: **DO NOT RELY ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES** because `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` is only `nvarchar(4000)`. You need to use `sys.sql_modules` where `definition` is `nvarchar(max)`. Look at my answer for an example queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DO NOT RELY ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES** because `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` is only `nvarchar(4000)`.  You need to `sys.sql_modules` where `definition` is nvarchar(max)

try any of these to find the procedure that you need to modify:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(s.name+'.'+o.name, 100) AS Object_Name,o.type_desc --, m.definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas  s ON o.schema_id=s.schema_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%'+@SearchValue+'%'
    ORDER BY 1

SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id) --, m.definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules  m
    WHERE m.definition like '%whatever%'

SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id), o.type_desc
        --,m.definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition like '%whatever%'
```

you can uncomment `m.definition` to list out the content, but I find it better to just ID all the procedures and then review them manually, because you don't want to run UPDATE commands on the system tables.  Script out the necessary procedures, make the changes (search/replace or manually), and then run the scripts!!!

Answer (score 3):

No.

I believe SQL Refactor from Redgate has this functionality. Otherwise you could script out all objects and either manually or via code do a search and replace.

SQL Server 2005 also has support for synonyms that might be of some help.

Comment: Yes, SQL Refactor has the Smart Rename feature, which changes all the references of the renamed object, as will SQL Prompt 5, which is due out very soon.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a chunk of SQL that you could use to retrieve the definition of stored procedures that match a certain search criteria.  You could simply change it to do a search and replace like Martin had suggested.

Simply change '%TABLE_NAME%' to your search criteria or the table name you would like to change.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%TABLE_NAME%' AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: **DO NOT RELY ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES** because `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` is only `nvarchar(4000)`. You need to use `sys.sql_modules` where `definition` is `nvarchar(max)`. Look at my answer for an example queries.

Answer (score 1):

If it's short term (like a testing database), the easier solution may be to make a `VIEW` for each table  that you changed, using the old name.  For instance, if you changed the table `tests` to `tests_new` you can do:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.tests
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.tests_new
```

All your procedures will that reference `dbo.tests` will actually look at the data in `dbo.tests_new`.

This is a **very very bad idea** if this will be a permanent/production DB, as it just adds a layer of obfuscation to your structure and will make it a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the table references in sprocs through the system data dictionary - you will have to get the script that creates the stored procedure and change the table names in the script.  If you have the scripts this is a simple search and replace for the most part.

If you don't have the scripts you can get the text of the stored procedure scripts from sys.sql_modules, or retrieve it through SSMS.